# Android Notification Bar

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to make an app that will allow you to have like a bar of settings or toggles like in cyanogen. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKkb0.png

Is there a specific way to attack this. It can be just a normal notification, but I want it to be in one bar with multiple icons. The api doesn't allow for this. I heard there is a way to access android's internal apis. The user should not have to root to make this work. Thank you soo much for any help you guys have to offer!

Comment: Look through Cyanogen's source

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this can't be done using the SDK. Check out the Cyanogen source for how they do it, but it is impossible to make it work across regular devices with stock ROMs.